# Asino che si arrabbia quando mangia troppo

Tags: word-usage, idioms, single-words, proverbs

Vorrei sapere com'è formulato il detto dell'asino che si arrabbia una volta che ha mangiato troppo. Mi viene in mente questo modo di dire italiano ma mi sfuggono le parole esatte.

Comment: Mai sentito questo proverbio. Comunque qui trovi I modi di dire con asino: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/A/asino.shtml e con mulo: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mulo_1.shtml

Comment: Per quel che vale, neppure io l'ho mai sentito e, sempre per quel che vale, non appare nel *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci.

Comment: No, la persona che me lo ha raccontato aveva detto che erano in tanti a saperlo.

Comment: Ci sono tratti detti a che fare con gli asini. In cinese esiste 黔驴技穷 , ma questo sito non lo riguarda.

Comment: Forse si tratta di un proverbio dialettale, in italiano non esiste. Comunque, che concetto dovrebbe esprimere questo proverbio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cercando di rispondere alla tua richiesta, ho trovato questo proverbio:

> L'asino, quando ha mangiato la biada, tira calci al corbello.

Non conoscendo tale proverbio, ho cercato il suo significato ma non sono riuscito a trovarlo.

Puoi trovare un elenco di proverbi sull'asino su questo [**sito**](http://aforismi.dossier.net/proverbi-italiani/proverbi1101.htm)

Comment: Sembra essere un proverbio toscano: https://books.google.it/books?id=Irx3oPMEwmUC&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=L%27asino,+quando+ha+mangiato+la+biada,+tira+calci+al+corbello.&source=bl&ots=gfySXJLKI6&sig=wkqEHwtwFTh72Maa5qDGaFgRGqg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih3qTx3IjTAhWJC8AKHX3mBAIQ6AEIJjAF#v=onepage&q=L'asino%2C%20quando%20ha%20mangiato%20la%20biada%2C%20tira%20calci%20al%20corbello.&f=false

Comment: @Gio: Ciao, potrebbe essere toscano ma avendo trovato lo stesso su diversi siti, dove non specificava la sua provenienza, non mi sono azzardato a proporre la sua provenienza

Comment: Comunque sia si tratta di un detto dialettale, non comune nella lingua italiana. Poi, che vuol dire?

Comment: Qui ci sono versioni dialettali lombarde, friulane ed emiliane: https://books.google.it/books?id=vXlfAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=L%27asino,+quando+ha+mangiato+la+biada,+tira+calci+al+corbello.&source=bl&ots=_t69EOGKzA&sig=btl7VtubNJjFfFzPdsOo_pYU0to&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2tJOR44jTAhWGC8AKHTHBBdEQ6AEILDAH#v=onepage&q=L'asino%2C%20quando%20ha%20mangiato%20la%20biada%2C%20tira%20calci%20al%20corbello.&f=false

Comment: @Gio: Nel secondo link il 494 (in grassetto) indica il proverbio in italiano e sotto lo traduce nei tre dialetti (lombardo, friulano ed emiliano). Forse è stato italianizzato ma come origine deriva da quella parte del Paese. Credo che in Italia quasi tutti i proverbi derivino da conoscenze dialettali

Comment: Sì è vero, ma non tutti diventano "italiani" ma rimangono modi di dire locali od arcaici. Secondo me, a parte le origini, questo proverbio è  probabilmente caduto in disuso.

Comment: Qui adddirittura ci danno l'equivalente inglese: https://books.google.it/books?id=PPCkCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT224&lpg=PT224&dq=L%27asino,+quando+ha+mangiato+la+biada,+tira+calci+al+corbello.&source=bl&ots=bwBLHfmcJC&sig=nf26tsIMqCNDPnM5Cd6mEf-AeyE&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj11O2S5YjTAhWkJsAKHTSUDuYQ6AEINDAJ#v=onepage&q=L'asino%2C%20quando%20ha%20mangiato%20la%20biada%2C%20tira%20calci%20al%20corbello.&f=false - ma anche quello inglese sembra poco comune.

Comment: @Gio: Sì sul fatto che sia poco comune concordo pienamente con te

Comment: @Gio: Che poi quello inglese sembra più derivante da quello leccese

Comment: Aggiungo la mia opinione sul possibile significato: "lo stolto si lamenta anche quando si soddisfano i suoi bisogni".